# Changing custom attribute source with jQuery does not update it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, elevatezoom

Quick Intro:
I'm using jQuery.elevateZoom-3.0.8 as to show zoomed picture.

1. SRC attribute is path to smaller/normal image
2. DATA-ZOOM-IMAGE attribute is path to bigger image that serves as a zoom.

HTML Code Below:

```
  <section id="designer-single" class="col-md-7" >
    <div class="magnifier-thumb-wrapper mc">
      <img class="front-magnify"  
      src="../../public/img/burn/purple-front.png"
      data-zoom-image="../../public/img/burn/purple-front-lg.png">
    </div>
 </section>
 <button class='back-image'>Click me</button>
```

Now I want image to change when user presses a button. Smaller image will change (SRC attribute), but bigger one will not refresh (data-zoom-image attribute) even though i change it with jQuery.

```
$('.back-image').on('click', function(){
    $('.front-magnify').attr('src', 'public/img/burn/purple-back.png');
    $('.front-magnify').attr('data-zoom-image', 'public/img/burn/purple-back-lg.png');
});
```

Question is: **how do I update state of custom attribute "data-zoom-image"** in elevateZoom.js so that it updates on **DOM?**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFvG7.png => without clicking

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0tUw.png => when changing

Example on Codepen:
  https://codepen.io/kenanbalija/pen/MojOEp

Comment: What you are doing is right, and it should work. Can you provide a [mcve] please? You have also omitted a `</div>` before the `</section>`.

Comment: Try using `.data()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @Musa tried already, did not work. I changed it here to attr for simplicity. In real code I'm using .data()

Comment: @kenanC [Works **flawlessly** for me.](http://output.jsbin.com/bolacuxaxa)

Comment: Still no [mcve].

Comment: What seems likely to be the problem is that you're changing the attribute successfully, but the code in `elevateZoom.js` is initing based on the original value and isn't watching for changes.

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes that's my question, dunno how to change that state.

Comment: @PraveenKumar this oK?

Answer (score 1):

What seems likely to be the problem is that you're changing the attribute successfully, but the code in elevateZoom.js is initing based on the original value and isn't watching for changes.

Based on your comment below and a quick look at the plugin source code, my earlier guesses (reinstantiate the plugin by calling `.elevateZoom` again, or use the `responsive` option) won't work.  This is a one-shot plugin, it's really not designed to be controllable after it's instantiated, so your options are pretty limited.

You could go brute-force and destroy the existing plugin (by removing the whole DOM element) before replacing it with a new one and reinstantiating the plugin.

Or, since you appear to be toggling between two different zoomable images, it may be simpler to instantiate them both separately and hide / reveal each as necessary, something along the lines of

```
$('.image').on('click', function(){
  $('.front-magnify, .back-magnify').toggleClass('hidden');
})
```

That'd be a tradeoff between bandwidth and code complexity, of course.

Comment: I've also tried calling elevateZoom() again but it does not work.
Thing is I'm going to use at least 20 pictures so it would be awfully lot of <img src="..""> in html code.

Comment: @kenanC oh well, it was worth a shot.  I've updated the answer, though neither of the solutions I can think of are clear winners.